# how to run a server socket on amazon EC2

Tags: java, android, sockets, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to write an android app that interacts with a server. I'm trying now to write the server side with sockets. I created an instance of ec2 and ran it. I connected to it with putty and ran a simple "hello world" java program. Now I'm trying to run a server which use a socket, but I get this as the server socket: ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=5667].
This is my code, very basic so far:

```
public class EchoServer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int portNumber = 5667;

    System.out.println("server socket main");

    try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
            ) {

        System.out.println(serverSocket.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out
                .println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "
                        + portNumber + " or listening for a connection");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

What should I do to run the server so I could connect to it via my andriod device?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track.  [0.0.0.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) simply means:

> A way to specify "any IPv4-interface at all". It is used in this way when configuring servers (i.e. when binding listening sockets).

Next, your server will need to listen for incoming connections by using [`SocketServer.accept()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29).

And then of course you'll want to receive and send data on the socket.  This [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) should help.

Finally, if you plan on serving multiple clients simultaneously with your server, you will want to consider *concurrency* and *scalability*, and perhaps consider using a framework like [Netty](http://netty.io).